# Display Results in correct format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve age data (which is in a decimal format) but I want to group the data into age brackets and display these under a column header.

Below is what I've tried and where I've got so far. However it displays the results with each age bracket as the column where as Id need the results to display like this for example:

| Age range | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 20-30 | 462 |
| 30-40 | 325 |

Code I've used below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Age <= 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '20-30',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '30-40',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '40-50',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '50-60',
        SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 61 AND 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '+60'
         FROM employeedata
WHERE NOT status IN ('Terminated', 'Retired')
And type = 'Employee'
```

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using. There are more sophisticated ways to do this but that depends on database that you are using.

Comment: Your SQL query should work as expected. Can you paste the results of that query?

Answer (score 2):

You a `case` expression as the aggregation key:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '30-40'
             WHEN Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN'40-50'
             WHEN Age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN '50-60'
             WHEN Age BETWEEN 61 AND 100 THEN '+60'
        END) as age_range, COUNT(*)
FROM employeedata
WHERE status NOT IN ('Terminated', 'Retired') AND
      type = 'Employee' 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '30-40'
               WHEN Age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN'40-50'
               WHEN Age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN '50-60'
               WHEN Age BETWEEN 61 AND 100 THEN '+60'
          END);
```

Note:  You probably want a filter `WHERE age >= 31` so you don't have a `NULL` group for younger employees.

Comment: I get error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
when I try run it like this